# Access token invalid after an unknown time

Tags: php, facebook

The access token of many users expire. My app require a offline access token. The user doesn't changed his password. I had the same problem with my facebook account. My password was not changed but the access token is invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facebook are deprecating the offline_access permission (as can be read here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/), and so I strongly recommend that you stop using it.

Also, you can use this: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/500/

Do you absolutely need this?  in most cases it's not really needed.

Comment: Yes i need this because my app do some things at night, when the user is in his bed.

the app show the difference of friends from two days. every night the app read all friends out and save them temporary in my database. then a script shows the difference.

Comment: I understand. As I see it you have two options: (1) When ever the user logs into your app calculate the difference between "now" and his last visit, instead of each day (or two). (2) Use the Real-time updates faecbook offer (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) it written there: "Here are the list of User connections to which you can subscribe: feed, friends, activities, interests, music, books, movies, television, likes, checkins", and so it seems like you can subscribe on the friends list change, I haven't tried it myself though

Comment: thank you for your answer. i had tried the realtime soloution but the problem is you can't see the change. Facebook tells you there is something, but you don't know if it a new friend or a removed friend.


(
    [object] => user
    [entry] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [uid] => 18298594XXX
                    [id] => 18298594XXX
                    [time] => 1329736270
                    [changed_fields] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => friends
                        )

                )

        )

)

Comment: Well, those are the options that facebook provide you with, there's another one which I forgot to write about, but it's being discussed in the same link I provided you with in my original post regarding the deprecation of the offline_access, it says that you can extend a valid access token using this: *https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APP_ID&client_secret=APP_SECRET&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN*, please read about it there.